Ubuntu 20.04 - How to find out how memory is used
I have an Ubuntu server I use to run a web application through Docker.
The image below shows the memory consumption (top—o %MEM) of the server with NO DOCKER CONTAINERS RUNNING. So, besides the memory used by Docker daemon (which uses 1.6%) and a few system services, there should be plenty of free memory. However, 67% of Memory is used.

What am I missing here?
How can I figure out what is using 2.5 GB of memory?

If you run a GUI it's probably a lot of it.

Hi there, there is no GUI running.
